# Changing all link destinations in a notebook

Tags: replacement

I have a bunch of cells containing text and hyperlinks. i.e. of the form:

```
Cell[TextData[{
 "Text",
 ButtonBox["Linktext",
  BaseStyle->"Hyperlink",
  ButtonData->"linktag"],
 "more text"
}], "Text"]
```

Is there a automated way of changing all of the link destinations so that they link to the same tag as the original, but in a different file, like this:

```
Cell[TextData[{
 "Text",
 ButtonBox["Linktext",
  BaseStyle->"Hyperlink",
  ButtonData->{"filename", "linktag"}],
 "more text"
}], "Text"]
```

Note that "linktag" is a different string for most of the cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modifying Rolf's answer slightly you have.

```
Button["change",
 NotebookPut[
  (NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]]) /. 
   ButtonBox["Linktext", BaseStyle -> "Hyperlink", ButtonData -> x_] ->
     ButtonBox["Linktext", BaseStyle -> "Hyperlink", 
     ButtonData -> {"filename", x}]
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: I can't make your button work. When I select a cell and click the button (which I put on a palette) nothing happens. Does it work on your machine?

And further: I tried changing "Linktext" to y_ and y to make it handle different link texts. Is that the right way to do it?

Comment: @Sofic Try it again.  It should open a new `Notebook` containing new versions.

Comment: Changing EvaluationNotebook to InputNotebook did the trick. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Sofic Yeah there was a mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Create a button, e.g., like this:

```
  Button["change",
  NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], (NotebookRead@EvaluationNotebook[])/."linktag" :>
 {"filename","linktag"}]]
```

Then select the cells you want to change and click the button: done.

Comment: Thank you, Rolf. It was something like that, I was looking for. It does however not solve my problem completely. I am sorry for not getting all details in my question:

The problem is that the "linktag"s are different for most of the cells.